# sp_get_query_template doesn't work with ODBC timestamp

Tags: sql-server, datetime, timestamp, odbc, sql-execution-plan

I have the following query:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT USER_NAME
    FROM LICENSE
    WHERE RESTRICTED_USE = 'T'
    AND ALLOCATED = 'T'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT USER_NAME
    FROM LICENSE
    WHERE RESTRICTED_USE = 'T'
    AND ALLOCATED = 'F'
    AND "TIME" >= {ts '2023-10-02 08:09:12'}
) AS TEMP_ALIAS
```

When I try to create a plan guide with sp_get_query_template the plan guide doesn't work and I think that the cause is the ODBC timestamp value.

```sql
DECLARE @stmt nvarchar(max);  
DECLARE @params nvarchar(max);  
EXEC sp_get_query_template   
    N'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT USER_NAME FROM LICENSE WHERE RESTRICTED_USE = ''T'' AND ALLOCATED = ''T'' UNION ALL SELECT USER_NAME FROM LICENSE WHERE RESTRICTED_USE = ''T'' AND ALLOCATED = ''F'' AND "TIME" >= {ts ''2023-10-02 08:09:12''})AS TEMP_ALIAS',  
    @stmt OUTPUT,   
    @params OUTPUT;  

    select @stmt
    select @params

EXEC sp_create_plan_guide   
    N'UsersCountTable',   
    @stmt,   
    N'TEMPLATE',   
    NULL,   
    @params,   
    N'OPTION(PARAMETERIZATION FORCED)';
```

I've tried also specifying timestamp parameter as:
VARCHAR(), DATEATIME, SMALLDATETIME, DATETIME2
with no success.

Comment: `AND "TIME" >= {ts '2023-10-02 08:09:12'}` isn't valid T-SQL?

Comment: That is how the application sends the query, it's not an error. I've also checked with  SQL Server Profiler.

Comment: Also, I think you can just do `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT USER_NAME)` in your inner query and avoid using a subquery at all.

Comment: umm, can you avoid odbc timestamp strings? What's the error you're getting when you run the plan guide?

Comment: Why did you delete your answer?

Comment: @dale-k
I thought that i've found the solution (thanks to your comment)

I changed the query by removing the double quotes thinking that this would work but after a while those execution plans reappeared.

Comment: @siggemannen i can't really avoid timestamp strings. This is an application query that I have no control over.

Answer (score 0):

I thought that i've found the solution (thanks to Dale K comment)

I changed the query by removing the double quotes thinking that this would work but after a while those execution plans reappeared.

[image]